# FME workbench convert Geotiff to ECW

Tags: geotiff-tiff, fme-form, ecw

Can anybody guide me with this error message from the FME workbench when I try to read a geotiff file and write it as a ECW file

> ERROR MESSAGE:  ECW writer: Unsupported band interpretation 'REAL32'.
>   Please convert the interpretation to one of the following valid types:
>   UINT8, GRAY8, GREEN8, RED8, ALPHA8, BLUE8 A fatal error has occurred.
>   Check the logfile above for details A fatal error has occurred. Check
>   the logfile above for details

How do I move on, can anybody link to some documentation eventually

Comment: I would rescale to 8 bit as intermediate step

Answer (score 3):

So, it appears that your TIF is in REAL32 which isn't supported by ECW. It's interesting that you're getting an error, because the **[writer documentation](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_ReadersWriters/ecw/ecw.htm)** states that:

> Any non-eight-bit source data will be rescaled to eight-bit.

However, you can force the data to be 8-bit by using a **[RasterInterpretationCoercer](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/rasterinterpretationcoercer.htm)**. I would set your output to RGB24 depending on your needs:
[image]

Other transformers to look at:

1. **[RasterBandInterpretationCoercer](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/rasterbandinterpretationcoercer.htm)**
2. **[RasterPaletteInterpretationCoercer](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/rasterpaletteinterpretationcoercer.htm)**

But they look at individual bands and palettes rather than the entire raster as a whole.

Comment: Good answer. I filed a problem report with the developer and docs teams about that info. I thought it might be because you are using numeric as opposed to RGB data (ie the band count is different too) but writing RGB48 didn't work either, so I guess that's not the answer. Anyway, we'll see what they say.

Comment: Just got confirmation that the documentation is wrong and will be fixed. We also expanded the error message to suggest the transformers to use to solve the problem. Hope that's useful.